# Handling SIGCHLD signal in Java

Tags: java, linux, bash, signals

I have a Java process, that (re)starts a Linux process, which spawns two daemonised child processes and dies.
(It's a wrapper to HAProxy, which is configured as a daemon with 2 Processes)

On every re-start, the process table has two more Zombie processes.
To prevent these Zombies, I have implemented the following:

```
final static SignalHandler _signalHandler = new SignalHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handle(Signal signal) {
        LOG.info("Received signal: {}",signal.getName());
    }
};

public HaproxyWrapper() {
    Signal.handle(new Signal("CHLD"), _signalHandler);
    LOG.info("Registered SIGCHLD signal handler");
}
```

I see the 'Registered SIGCHLD' log in the output, but never the 'Received signal: SIGCHLD'.

Am I doing this wrong?

Alternatively, 'the simplest thing that could possibly work' - I could create a shell script called start_haproxy.sh which will both call haproxy and handle the SIGCHLD. How do I handle SIGCHLD in bash? (handle -> ignore)

Thanks.

Comment: When you receive this, the child has exited. But why should this help you - the child processes exist as demons.

Comment: laune, can you please elaborate? the Child (haproxy) has two children. So we have a grand-parent-parent-child situation: haproxyWrapper (alive) --> haproxy (dies) --> haproxy daemon 1,2 (alive).

Comment: The haproxWrapper would receive a SIGCHLD. If the daemons really are daemons the shouldn't end up as zombies, and knowing (in the wrapper) that haproxy dies doesn't help anyway.

Comment: What's the reason of HAproxy dying?

Comment: @laune That's just how HAProxy works, in daemon mode: Main process brings up two workers and dies.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure that Java already ignores the SIGCHLD which is why you can't trap it. Only a running process would get this signal and if you `Process.waitFor()` you will be notified that a child process has died.

Zombie processes are ones which cannot be killed, i.e. they live on after they should have died, usually due to a problem in the OS.  I suspect you are concerned about orphaned processes, i.e. when you have a process whose parent had died.

The simplest way to prevent that is to make your parent wait for it's children to die.

BTW daemon processes often run as orphaned processes.  Are you sure this is really a problem?

Comment: Yeah, it's a problem if I have a hundred lines like: "101      31988  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Zs   09:42   0:00 [haproxy] <defunct>". So in my case, it's Java ProcessBuilder that calls HAProxy which creates two processes and dies. I'm not sure if Java is at fault, HAProxy, or myself :)

Comment: "I am pretty sure that Java already ignores the SIGCHLD which is why you can't trap it".  -> I was able to install a signal handler for SIGCHLD just fine: https://github.com/jumarko/clojure-experiments/blob/master/src/clojure_experiments/java/processes.clj#L73-L74. The only related thing I found is this bug but that's really old:

Answer (score 1):

A zombie process exists if its parent still exists but has not yet done a `wait` for the child. Why Java isn't doing that, I don't know. If the parent exits, the child simply reparents to PID 1 (`init`); in this case it can't become a Zombie. This is one reason why double forking is utilized (ensuring that the daemon is reparented to `init` as soon as it starts as its immediate parent will already have exited).

The easy way around it is to use a shell script which properly daemonizes. Depending on your Linux distribution, you may already have a utility that does this (e.g. `start-stop-daemon`. Otherwise, you want something like

```
#/bin/bash
(nohup /path/to/program 0<&- &>/dev/null &)&
```

which does the requisite double fork. There is a longer but more thorough way to do it [here](http://blog.n01se.net/blog-n01se-net-p-145.html).

Comment: Hi & Thanks. I tried it: Java now runs a script exactly like you specified. Still have zombies: One owned by 'root' wit  [haproxy_sigchld] <defunct> and two as before, owned by 101, [haproxy] <defunct>.